# How can I prove or disprove that the following function is bijection?

Tags: hash, bit-manipulation

For a research project, I tried to prove or disprove that a function called xxhash128_low is a bijection from 64 bit unsigned integer to 64 bit unsigned integer. I have shown that it is sufficient to prove that the following critical code is a bijection:

```
Input: a 64-bit integer x
0. Let c=0x9e3779b185ebcaa7
1. Let x_low= the 8-low bytes of c*x.
2. Let x_high= the 8-high bytes of c*x.
3. w= x_high+2*x_low.
4  y= shift right 3 bits of w.
5. return x_low XOR y.
```

What I have proved till now: returning only the low 64 bits, x_low, can be shown to be a permutation. Also, y can be expressed as a function of x_low (i.e., y=f(x_low)).

Comment: You could try using Z3 to check whether there exists a collision for this function, i.e., whether it is bijective.

Comment: I don't know whether this is useful, but I think w has a close connection to 2c*x mod 2^65 - 1 (it's equal, or equal +/- 2^64, or something like that; I didn't work out the exact details).

Comment: Or, you could try using Floyd's cycle finding algorithm, or a more sophisticated successor (such as one using distinguished points) to see whether iterating this function leads to a cycle.  Heuristically, if this function is not bijective, I bet there is a decent chance you find a collision after  something like 2^32 iterations.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection

Comment: This can be very useful if we can express the function as a linear transformation over a field, checking the determinate

Comment: I ran your function with all possible $c$s in the 8-bit case. The only value for which the function was bijective was $c=1$. So it is likely that your function is not bijective.

Comment: Assuming my implementation is correct, both 2DCE4F983BBEB685 and 72E04DBED1540FE1 map to A5C53FE6E277BD92.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  I tried these functions. Apparently, I had a mistake on the $c$ parameter.
I will be very gladly if you can  run again your program with the new $c$ value :)

Comment: I can, but it's much better if you coded it up yourself, so that next time that you find a mistake, you won't need to contact me.

Comment: Sure. I tried to do brute force and Floyd's cycle finding algorithm. I did not found one. Did you used the Z3 solver? or just the brute force?

Comment: I used Floyd's cycle detection algorithm. It took 32 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: Thanks! I will try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, the hash function was defined as follows:

- Input: a 64-bit unsigned integer $x$.
- Calculate $(9E3779B185EBCB87)_{16} \cdot x = 2^{64} x_h + x_l$, where $x_l,x_h$ are 64-bit unsigned integers.
- Output $x_l \oplus \lfloor (x_h + 2x_l)/8 \rfloor$.

Under this definition, there is a collision: both $(2DCE4F983BBEB685)_{16}$ and $(72E04DBED1540FE1)_{16}$ map to $(A5C53FE6E277BD92)_{16}$.

You can find such collisions using a [cycle detection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).

Comment: While it did not took 32 seconds (10 minutes)- there is a collision also in the modified version. So thanks:)